# UITextView user defined runtime placeholder attribute makes app crash - iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextview, ios7.1

[image]

I have set the placeholder runtime attributes as given in the image.

It works perfectly in iOS 8+ and crashes in iOS 7 with the following issue: 
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UITextView 0x14bd4800> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _placeholderLabel.`

Can anyone help me identify the issue?

Comment: Try with "placeholderLabel" not "_placeholderLabel"

Comment: @anhtu I tried that already. It doesnt make a difference.

Comment: `placeholderLabel` is a `UILabel`? It's not a attribute of UITextView.